# sequelize-nodejs how do I fetch data from other fields of a table

Tags: jquery, node.js, sockets, sequelize.js

Hi I'm developing a chat app and just want to know how do I fetch data from other fields of a table on mysqldatabase using sequelize because I'm totally new on this. 
Here is how I tried to do it:

```
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
  // Send all previously sent messages
  for( i in messages ) {
    socket.emit('chat message', messages[i]);
  }

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);

    // Push the message into the in-memory array.
    messages.push(msg);

    // Storage the message for when the application is restarted.
    sequelize.query('INSERT INTO chat_storage(chat) VALUES("'+msg+'")').success(function() {
      // Insert was successful.
    }).error(function (err) {
      // Error inserting message
    });

    // Send the message to everyone
   io.sockets.emit('chat message', msg);

  });
});

function getStdout(command, args, fn) {
  var childProcess = require('child_process').spawn(command, args);
  var output = '';
  childProcess.stdout.stdoutetEncoding('utf8');
  childProcess.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    output += data;
  });
  childProcess.on('close', function() {
    fn(output);
  });
}

// Load Messages
sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM chat_storage ').success(function (rows)  {
  for( i in rows ) {
      messages.push(rows[i].chat);
      messages.push(rows[i].fname);
  }
  getStdout('php', ['message.php'], function(output) {
    validator = output;
    http.listen(3000, function(){
      // Start server.
    });
  });
}).error(function (err) {
  // Error!
});
```

now this script works but the problem is that both th field chat and fname loads on the same boat which is not what I want because the fname field should be loaded on a separate `div`

here is how I load them

```
  <?php startblock('script') ?>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io();


  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
     $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){

var li = $(
      '<div class="message user"><div class="message-info">'+
      '<img width="40" height="40" src="temp/user/jessamine.jpg">' +
          '<div class="message-timestamp">' +
          ' <time datetime="" class="timeago uk-text-small">09:22 am</time>' +
          '</div></div><b></b>' +
        ' <div class="message-data">' +
        ' <p></p></div></div>');

    // use the 'text' method to escape malicious user input
    li.find('p').addClass('bubble').text(msg);


 $('#message-list').append(li); 


  });


<?php endblock(); ?>
```

With this script the fname data should not be loaded but instead it is also loaded on the `<p>`.. which is I think its weird... Please help me how do I do it?